# How to save Blob in Ionic

Tags: pdf, ionic-framework, ionic2, blob

I am new to ionic framework, actually I am getting byte array as response from back end service and converting it to blob. How can I save it to PDF in ionic?

```
var blob = new Blob([res], { type: 'application/pdf' });
```

Here res is the response (byte array) from the service.

Code

```
var blob = new Blob([res], { type: 'application/pdf' });         

        let fileName="Receipt.pdf";         
        let filePath = (this.platform.is('android')) ? 
        this.file.externalRootDirectory : this.file.cacheDirectory;

        this.file.writeFile(filePath, fileName, blob, { replace: true }).then((fileEntry) => {

          console.log("File created!");          
          this.fileOpener.open(fileEntry.toURL(), 'application/pdf')
            .then(() => console.log('File is opened'))
            .catch(err => console.error('Error openening file: ' + err));
        })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.error("Error creating file: " + err);
            throw err;  
          });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

In order to SAVE the PDF, you'll need to use some cordova plugins.  Ionic has some nice wrappers around these [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/).  Check out the File, File Transfer, and File Opener plugins.

Here's some example code you could use once you get these plugins incorporated into your project:

```
    var blob = new Blob([res], { type: 'application/pdf' });

    //Determine a native file path to save to
    let filePath = (this.appConfig.isNativeAndroid) ? this.file.externalRootDirectory : this.file.cacheDirectory;

    //Write the file
    this.file.writeFile(filePath, fileName, blob, { replace: true }).then((fileEntry: FileEntry) => {

      console.log("File created!");

      //Open with File Opener plugin
      this.fileOpener.open(fileEntry.toURL(), data.type)
        .then(() => console.log('File is opened'))
        .catch(err => console.error('Error openening file: ' + err));
    })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error("Error creating file: " + err);
        throw err;  //Rethrow - will be caught by caller
      });
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, I have tried this but it's giving error message cannot display PDF(doc is of invalid format).

Comment: Can you post your code and the exact error you're seeing?  Also, are you running this as web, or on android/ios?  These plugins will only work for android/ios.

Comment: I have edited my question and I am running this on android emulator.

Comment: Thanks.  Which catch block is bombing?  What is the exact error?

Comment: I am getting that error message in android toast. This method is not throwing any error.

Comment: I see.  Do you have a PDF reader (e.g. Acrobat, google drive)?  Can you open other PDF's on the device?  It may be helpful to try to display the PDF via ionic web app and see if that works:  `let fileUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);  window.location.href = fileUrl;`